# Cisco 6509 as PPPoE BRAS

Tags: cisco, cisco-6500, layer2, pppoe

I have read that SIP-400 and SPA are compatible with 6509 series switch. These SIP and SPA are used to terminate PPP sessions on 7600 routers. If I installed this SIP and SPA (SPA-5X1GE-V2 for example) on my 6509 chassis, could I configure the switch to terminate PPPoE sessions as a [BRAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadband_Remote_Access_Server)? In that case, which IOS would support this feature?

The switch has SUP720-PFC3BXL supervisors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have read that SIP-400 and SPA are compatible with 6509 series switch. These SIP and SPA are used to terminate PPP sessions on 7600 routers. If i installed this SIP and SPA (SPA-5X1GE-V2 for example) on my 6509 chassis, could i configure the switch to terminate PPPoE sessions? In that case, which IOS would support this feature?
>
> The switch has SUP720-PFC3BXL supervisors.

I have some good news, and bad news:

Good news, the [Cisco 7600 supports PPPoE on 7600-SIP-400](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios-xml/ios/bbdsl/configuration/12-4t/bba-pppoe-baa.html#GUID-86B54017-934C-44DA-9B60-B96A8CF0D603), see the [SIP-400 PPPoE configuration guide](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios-xml/ios/bbdsl/configuration/12-4t/bba-pppoe-baa.html#GUID-86B54017-934C-44DA-9B60-B96A8CF0D603).  However, starting in IOS 15.2(4)S, the 7600 does *not* support PPPoE.<sup>1</sup>

Bad news, PPPoE on SIP-400 requires 12.2SR, and the [Sup720-3CXL is *not* supported in 12.2SR](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/7600/Hardware/12.2SR_supported_hw/7600_hwd.html#wp1030645).<sup>2</sup>; however, Sup720-3B / 3BXL *are* supported in 12.2SR (see the [List of 12.2SR supported hardware](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/7600/Hardware/12.2SR_supported_hw/7600_hwd.html) for more details).

PPPoE on [SIP-400](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps368/product_data_sheet0900aecd8027c9e6.html) Requirements:

- [RSP720](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps368/product_data_sheet0900aecd8057f3b6.html), Sup720-3B, or Sup720-3BXL
- When using 7600-SIP-400, [Load at least IOS 12.2(33)SRC](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/246912) (or later 12.2SR) on the system
- The [7600 ES+ Series supports PPPoE starting in 12.2(33)SRE](https://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/iosswrel/ps8802/ps6970/ps1838/prod_bulletin0900aecd805ddce3.pdf)

Restrictions:

- Customers are discouraged from loading 12.2SR on a Catalyst 6500 branded chassis for PPPoE functionality.  Please contact your Cisco account manager if you want to do this.
- Sup720-3C is not supported, only Sup720-3B, Sup720-3BXL and RSP720 are supported
- Up to 8000 PPPoE sessions per SIP-400, maximum 32000 PPPoE sessions per chassis (across multple linecards)
- PBR is not supported on Virtual Template interfaces

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>After Feb 2012, Cisco encourages customers to use the ASR9K for PPPoE termination.</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>The 6500 and 7600 used to share a lot of hardware and software (sometimes on different SW releases), but [that sharing has decreased](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/iosswrel/ps8802/ps6970/ps6017/ps9673/product_bulletin_c25-503086.html) after the release of 12.2(33)SR / 12.2(33)SX.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! So, all these restrictions are for both chassis 7600 and 6500 or only for the 7600?

Comment: Certainly... pppoe is limited to the 7600 when using 12.2sr... I hope you have some Sup720-3Bs lying around otherwise, it's an expenditure.  Let me know how this works out for you, I'm curious...

Comment: Yes, i have SUP720-3BXLs...That's way i thought about trying to terminate PPP sessions on the 6509 instead of buying a 7206VXR for example...Of course I'll report with results!!

Comment: Yeah, PPPoE on Sup720 + SIP-400 scales much better than [PPPoE on the NPE-G2](https://puck.nether.net/pipermail/cisco-bba/2012-September/001391.html "Most people run between 5k - 10k PPPoE sessions, max on NPE-G2"), because on the 7600, PPPoE is distributed to SIP-400 HW

Comment: I have one 7206VXR with 3'7K PPPoE Session but CPU average load is 42% (limit i think is on traffic... it supports about 1'8G and we have 1G sometimes)

Comment: @RS1983, I used to work for this BU and emailed some old contacts to see if they had anything to add to the answer; please see my updates.

Comment: I am thinking about changing the 6509 chassis for a 7609 one and using the same linecards and supervisors. But first of all i need that 12.2SR IOS and check if my config (QinQ tunnels and more) in the 6509 would work in the 7600. The 6509 is our core switch and i must be very sure about this. Thank you for your updates!! Very helpful!!

Comment: Is the IOS c7600s72033-advipservicesk9-mz.122-33.SRE1.bin compatible with the 6509 chassis? I have two SUP7203BXL running with SSO redundancy and i would like to use one of these in a 7600 chassis. I thought in upload the ios to the not active SUP and then quit from one chassis (6509) and insert it in the 7609 . Do you recommend this or would follow another plan?